# Стеки на основе списков C++

Tags: c++, списки

Не получается написать функцию очистки стека идёт всегда завершение программы.

```
void Clean(Stack *Data)
{
    Stack *temp;
    temp = Data->head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)  
     {
       temp->next = temp;
       delete temp;
       temp = NULL;
       temp->next = temp->next->next;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Harry, стек на основе односвязного списка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну что же вы делаете!

```
delete temp;
temp = NULL;
temp->next = temp->next->next;
```

Удалили, обнулили - и хотите по нулевому указателю поле `next` получить!

Как я понимаю, у вас не стек, а односвязный список?

Не видя ваш `Stack`, просто по предположениям о нем :) - то вам надо что-то вроде

```
Stack * curr = Data->head, *next;
while(curr)
{
    next = curr->next;
    delete curr;
    curr = next;
}
Data->head = nullptr;
```

Comment: Знаю, что делаю что-то не так.

Comment: Но не понимаю, в чём ошибка моя.

Comment: Я не вдаюсь в логику программы, просто две строчки: `temp = NULL;` и `temp->next = temp->next->next;`. После первой у вас `temp` - нулевой указатель. ЕГО НЕЛЬЗЯ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ для каких-либо обращений к памяти. Но вы делаете именно это , пытаясь прочесть `temp->next`, не говоря уж записать...

Comment: Спасибо, понял.